# No puedo leer un archivo .json. C++

Tags: c++, json

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo .json utilizando jsoncpp.cpp y json.h, cuando utilizo la función `parse` el programa me tira varios errors, los cuales dicen lo siguiente:

- C4996 'Json::Reader': Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.
- C4996 'Json::Reader::parse': Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.
- C4996 'Json::Reader::Reader': Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.
- C4996 'Json::Reader::__autoclassinit2': Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.

El código que tengo para leer el archivo es el siguiente:

```
void AdminPacientes::cargaDatos()
{
    ifstream archivoPacientes("datos_geneticos.json");
    Paciente* tempP = nullptr;
    Enfermedad* tempE = nullptr;

    Json::Value objeto;
    Json::Reader reader;
    reader.parse(archivoPacientes, objeto);

    for (int i = 0;i < objeto.size();i++)
    {
        tempP = new Paciente;
        tempP->setId(objeto[i]["Id"].asString());
        tempP->setNombre(objeto[i]["Nombre"].asString());
        tempP->setTelefono(objeto[i]["Telefono"].asString());
        tempP->setCorreo(objeto[i]["Correo"].asString());
        tempP->setSecuencia(objeto[i]["Secuencia"].asString());
        for (int i = 0; i < objeto.size();i++)
        {
            tempE = new Enfermedad;
            tempE->setNombre(objeto[i]["Nombre"].asString());
            tempE->setSecuencia(objeto[i]["Secuencia"].asString());
            tempP->agregar(tempE);
        }
        this->listaPacientes->agregaFinal(tempP);
        tempP = nullptr;
    }
    archivoPacientes.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que `json::reader` no debería usarse de acuerdo a lo que comentan [aquí](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/815).

Así mismo, ese mensaje que indicas es sólo un warning y, al parecer, tienes todo configurado para que los warnings sean errores fatales.

En la [documentación](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/example/readFromString/readFromString.cpp) de la librería que intentas usar (siempre hay que revisar la documentación, antes que cualquier cosa) también está un ejemplo de cómo usar CharBuilder, que pongo a continuación como referencia:

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include <iostream>
/**
 * \brief Parse a raw string into Value object using the CharReaderBuilder
 * class, or the legacy Reader class.
 * Example Usage:
 * $g++ readFromString.cpp -ljsoncpp -std=c++11 -o readFromString
 * $./readFromString
 * colin
 * 20
 */
int main() {
  const std::string rawJson = R"({"Age": 20, "Name": "colin"})";
  const auto rawJsonLength = static_cast<int>(rawJson.length());
  constexpr bool shouldUseOldWay = false;
  JSONCPP_STRING err;
  Json::Value root;

  if (shouldUseOldWay) {
    Json::Reader reader;
    reader.parse(rawJson, root);
  } else {
    Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
    const std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader> reader(builder.newCharReader());
    if (!reader->parse(rawJson.c_str(), rawJson.c_str() + rawJsonLength, &root,
                       &err)) {
      std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
  const std::string name = root["Name"].asString();
  const int age = root["Age"].asInt();

  std::cout << name << std::endl;
  std::cout << age << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para leer archivos `json` yo suelo usar **"nlohmann json"** que es la librería más usada en C++ para esto. Lo cual no quiere decir que sea la mejor, pero si que al menos cuenta con una gran comunidad detrás que debugea errores y le da soporte.

Puedes ver toda la [documentación y archivos de descarga en su Github.](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) Para usarla es muy sencillo tienes que seguir los siguientes pasos:

### 1. Agregar archivo .hpp

Agregas en una carpeta el `.hpp` que lo puedes descargar de dentro del Github [aquí](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/include/nlohmann/json.hpp)

Podemos llamar a dicha carpeta *"nlohmann"* ya que es el nombre de la librería, por lo que nuestra estructura de carpetas quedaría así:

```
carpeta_raiz
|
|------- fichero_principal_ejemplo.cpp
|
|
|------- carpeta_ejemplo
|
|
|------- nlohmann
```

### 2. Importar y usar la libería

Hay distintas formas de usar esta librería y sus funciones, como puedes ver en la documentación que te he dejado más arriba. Sin embargo para mi la más simple es este ejmplo que te explico debajo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
#include <fstream>

using json = nlohmann::json;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream dict_json1_read("cost_matrix.json");
    json dict_json1 = json::parse(dict_json1_read);

    cout<<dict_json1;
    return 0;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
{"1":0.0,"10000007":23.09,"12":17.98,"23":21.49,"25":18.36,"26":31.42,"27":46.62}
```

#### Explicación

1. Usando `include` y `using` importamos la librería y creamos el tipo de dato que vamos a usar, en este caso `json`.
2. Usamos la librería `fstream` para cargar los datos que tenemos en formato `.json`
3. Una vez los tenemos cargados utilizamos el método `::parse()` de `json` para parsear los datos anteriormente cargados.
4. Por último puse un `cout` simplemente como ejemplo para que se viera como es la variable.